# keep previous value when update query run in C#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I am currently trying to keep previous value of field in database if new value is null. However, the question now is that, how can I keep old value when using Parameters.AddWithValue?

```
SqlCommand AddToFarms = new SqlCommand("Update Farms set " +
                           "ProductiveTreesNo=@ProductiveTreesNo," +
                           "MainCropsType=@MainCropsType" +
                           " where OBJECTID =@OBJECTID", connection2);
if (item.ProductiveTreesNo == null)
    AddToFarms.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductiveTreesNo", DBNull.Value);
else
    AddToFarms.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductiveTreesNo", item.ProductiveTreesNo);
if (item.MainCropsType == null)
    AddToFarms.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MainCropsType", DBNull.Value);
else
    AddToFarms.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MainCropsType", item.MainCropsType);
```

Comment: `coalesce(@ProductiveTreesNo,ProductiveTreesNo)`

Comment: I did what you mentioned , but I got this error " Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'coalesce'."

Comment: Post your new code with the changes.

Comment: Not in a comment. Update the question. Anyway, that's not what was mentioned so you didn't do as instructed. Maybe you should take the time to do some reading on how `COALESCE` works and learn something.

Comment: `Update Farms set ProductiveTreesNo = coalesce(@ProductiveTreesNo, ProductiveTreesNo), MainCropsType = coalesce(@MainCropsType , MainCropsType) ...`

Comment: I read how COALESCE works , by mistake I post the code

Comment: Okay well try it again now.